# How to select which GWT module to load on host page?

Tags: java, gwt

While working on a site, I want to have several modules in my GWT project representing the different areas of the site. E.g : Statistics, Shopping, Messages, etc. Each being a different module.

On each of these pages, I want to insert the gwt `<script>` tag and pass on to it which module to load. E.g on messages page, it will only load + display the messages module, and so on.

Is that possible? E.g by setting a hidden form field, and have GWT get its value to determine which module to use?

If not, is it possible to compile each module separately? If so can you guide me a little on how to do it? (E.g, will there be a new folder made in the /war/ directory for each module, or would the files all be merged?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** compile each module separately, you just need to specify a entry-point for your modules like this:

```
<entry-point class='class extends com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint' />
```

Then, provide you have your module defined as `<module rename-to='moduleName'>` in *.gwt.xml, you can load this module by insert `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="moduleName/moduleName.nocache.js"></script>` in your html.

Comment: So for each module, there will be a separate folder generated by GWT in the /war/ directory containing its javascript, css files, etc?

Comment: Also, when you compile from eclipse, will it compile each module or is there a way to specify to only compile one, e.g if the others are unchanged since last compile?

Comment: @ClickUpvote yes, each module, there will be a separate folder named moduleName generated by GWT. and yes, you can specify to only compile one, the modules to be compiled is the arguments of com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler, see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideJavaToJavaScriptCompiler for more information.